# Add Namespace to Node using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, wix, heat

I am trying to use WiX 3.7 to produce an MSI installer. I'm using heat.exe to create a wxs fragment from the contents of my build directory, which I then reference in a separate static wxs file. I also need to apply an XSL transformation to this file in order to add a "ServiceInstall" node to one of the Components. Adding the node is fairly simple even for an XSL noob like me. However, in order for the resultant XML to be well-formed, I need to add a reference to the WixUtil extension both to the Wix node and the Fragment node. So, my XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="Main">
        <Component Id="xyz" Guid="{123}">
            <File Id="xyz" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.mainDir)\some.exe" />
            <util:ServiceInstall Id="xyz" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Name="someService" DisplayName="someService" Description="An example service." etc="etc" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
 </Wix>
```

And I need it to be this:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Fragment xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <DirectoryRef Id="Main">
        <Component Id="xyz" Guid="{123}">
            <File Id="xyz" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.mainDir)\some.exe" />
            <util:ServiceInstall Id="xyz" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Name="someService" DisplayName="someService" Description="An example service." etc="etc" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
 </Wix>
```

I am dynamically adding the namespace declaration to the Wix element and that works fine, using the following code, borrowed from another answer on StackOverflow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:old="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
exclude-result-prefixes="old">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="pNewNamespace" select="'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'"/>
<xsl:variable name="vXsi" select="document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='util']"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, when I try to use the same method to add the declaration to the Fragment node, it returns garbled xml. It feels like this should be a very simple, straightforward task to accomplish. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you need the declaration `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"` twice? Its presence on the root element should suffice.

Comment: I assumed it would - but the <Fragment> node doesn't seem to inherit it. When trying to build my WixProj with the declaration added to the root element but not to <Fragment>, I get the following: "The Component element contains an unexpected child element" and the accompanying "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'xyz'" messages.

ETA - thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: The util namespace isn't used for ServiceInstall. I've changed the XSL but left the explanation.

An XML namespace prefix needs to be defined only in the elements that it is used in or in an ancestor. The XSL processor should output it in a suitable place.

Are you doing the transformation is two steps? That shouldn't be necessary and could be what is causing you trouble.

For this heat command, this XSL will do the entire modification you've discussed; You might want to adjust the heat argument for your situation, though.

```
heat dir bin -out heated.wxs -t ServiceInstall.xsl -var var.mainDir
```

ServiceInstall.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="wix"
    >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[wix:File/@Source='$(var.mainDir)\some.exe']">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <wix:ServiceInstall 
            Id="xyz" 
            Type="ownProcess" 
            Vital="yes" 
            Name="someService" 
            DisplayName="someService" 
            Description="An example service." 
            etc="etc" />
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```